# Scala: handle different constructor when extending a parameterised Class

Tags: scala, constructor, user-defined-functions, abstract, extends

I am writing a scala code, and want to handle different constructor when extending a parameterised Class. For example:

```
class Person (val name:String, val age: Int)
class Employee(name:String, age:Int, val position:String) 
      extends Person(name, age)
```

However, what I want is that Employee can have two constructors one of which takes information of Person to construct, one takes another Employee to construct:

```
val emply1 = new Employee(yzh, 30, CEO)
val emply2 = new Employee(emply1)
```

If I want both constructors works, how can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want two constructors, you simply write two constructors:

```
class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)
class Employee(name: String, age: Int, val position: String) extends 
  Person(name, age) {
  def this(e: Employee) = this(e.name, e.age, e.position)
}

val emply1 = new Employee("yzh", 30, "CEO")
val emply2 = new Employee(emply1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add an axillary constructor.

```
class Employee(name:String, age:Int, val position:String)
  extends Person(name, age) {
  def this(emp: Employee) = this(emp.name, emp.age, emp.position)
}
```

If your `Employee` were a `case class` then you could do this instead.

```
val emply1 = Employee("yzh", 30, "CEO")
val emply2 = emply1.copy()
```